# wp-login.php getting renamed automatically

Tags: php, wordpress, web

i have a little information about website security and other things in this field.

i have website with wordpress installed on it
but my wp-login.php gets renamed automatically
i dont know why but after random time my wp-login.php gets renamed to something like wp-login_mf95I.php!

is this a security hole ?

my wp version is latest
tnx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a fresh copy and compare wp-login.php to the wp-login.php file that's getting renamed. Are there any differences? Do you have any plugins installed? If so can you list those? Are any supposed to increase security? It could be malicious code but it could just as easily be a plugin attempting to increase security.

Comment: btw when this happens i have two wp-login files. first is the renamed file (wp-login_mf95I.php) and also there is a wp-login.php with 0 kb size! i'll have to overwrite every time. it is not plugin problem. i disabled all of them and still had this issue

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a security hole.
Export your content and fresh install your wordpress.

Comment: Any additional intel on this? Core exploit? Email security {at} wordpress.org if you believe it is!